# Gnu Emacs : how to minimize it to system tray?

Tags: windows, emacs, notification-area

i've been searching around for a way to minimize to tray or hide Emacs app, i don't really want to close it every time i finish using it nor i want to have it's icon showing on taskbar and "alt-tab" feature ...

i've found some 3rd-party apps that makes all applications minimize to tray, but that's not really what i want and i'd prefer to avoid using other programs..

if you have a 3rd party app that does ::

1- allow me to minimize normally & minimize to tray as different options

2- allow me to chose what applications would this affect

I'd not mind using it if its only way

thanks  :]

**INFO**

1. Windows 8.1 x64
2. Gnu Emacs 23.4.1
3. I'm currently opening it using emacsclientw.exe
4. /.emacs includes : ( server-start )

> "C:\Program Files\Emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -na "C:\Program
>   Files\Emacs\bin\runemacs.exe" %1"

**TL;DR**

i want to minimize emacs to system tray.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand, closing and reopening emacsclient is what you are supposed to do, the deamon is always running, so when you close emacsclient and reopen it, it should be instant as every startup lisp is already loaded into memory.